# Use simple_form with bootstrap - undefined method 'error_messages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I try to use simple_form for make my form view more readible

It looks now like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @some_object, url: some_url, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.input :phone %>
  <div class="form-row">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <a class="btn btn-link" href="<%= object.to_url %>" title="Cancel" data-event="post_cancel_click"><span>Cancel</span></a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately I receive `undefined method`error_messages' for SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0xb385c948`

When I don't use error_messages then form is rendered, but when error occurs it is not showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's as far as I know correct. Simple form doesn't know what '`error_messages`' is. When you check the documentation, it states:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

> This will generate an entire form with labels for user name and password as well, **and render errors by default** when you render the form with invalid data (after submitting for example).

I believe there might be at least two solutions for your problem:

1) You can specify in your simple_form.rb initializer file with which tag your error message will be wrapped, like this:

```
b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :error }
```

Check [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Upgrading-to-Simple-Form-2.0) for more or in docs

2) Use  `f.error` helper, like it is described in [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)